# p2os groovy C++ Velocity and C++ Pose Listener

Tags: ros, roscpp, ros-groovy, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need help in compiling the test sketches for listening and sending information to the robot from the tutorial `http: //www. ros. org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials`.
How to set the dependencies and set the right paths to  header files? Will it be enough to compile them with g++ and then start it using the line from the Tutorial `rosrun p2osTutorial eo_pose`. But what is the p2osTutorial? Is it some package, from which the compiled file will be started?

---

We have created p2osTutorials package and C++ listener works correctly.
Unfortunately C++ velocity doesn't make the robot move. The first problem was solved adding the line  `ros::init(argc, argv, "velo");` to the file, but the robot still didn't move. We build the driving file the same way as the pose file (just added a new velo.cc file to the p2osTutorial/src) and edited the CMakeList.txt. I think we are doing something wrong?

---

Thanks for your answer. We compiled it the normal way but it seems that the `cmd_pub.publish(cmd_msg);` line does not move the robot

When we start the node we printed out the cmd_msg it looks fine to us (robot should move).
linear:
x: 0.5
y: 0
z: 0
angular:
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0

After looking at the tutorials (again ;) with the new informations that we have now) i can see that the code from your tutorial C++ Velocity is almost the same. I guess we still have any problems in our dependencies or something like that.

Thanks and regards

---

Thank you for the fast anwser and sorry that we did not tell this the motors are enabled and the robot drives over the simple commandline like: `rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 10000 '[1, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 0]'`
in the scenario we try to test the C++ Velocity program we can not "move" the robot because the weels are "blocked"

or do we need to enable the motors in the way you actually described

Thanks again

---

Thank you for the tutorial, it worked fine everything could be compiled and also the program starts. The motors are enabled by the enableMotor command.
But the robot won't drive neither with the GUI_Command nor with the C++ Velocity program. We see that some kind of data is send in the output of the terminals. The question is if this is a ROS problem or is something missing that is essentially is needed to drive with the robot.

Thanks and regards

---

We will geht with the ropstopic list:

- /aio /base_controller/command
  /battery_state /cmd_motor_state
  /cmd_vel /diagnostics /dio
  /gripper_control /gripper_state
  /motor_state /pose /ptz_control
  /ptz_state /rosout /rosout_agg /sonar
  /tf

C++ Velocity and echo_pose is active (p2os driver and so on also). I hope there is something in this list that is missing...

Thanks

---

[image description http://oi43.tinypic.com/2dmgt3l.jpg](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2dmgt3l.jpg)

I hope this will clear things up thank you gain

---

sorry found out that there is another mode and i can see where the problem is. The Veloce program has no connection to the p2os driver

[image description http://i39.tinypic.com/2r2qfsw.jpg](http://i39.tinypic.com/2r2qfsw.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65406/p2os-groovy-c++-velocity-and-c++-pose-listener/) by [roman27](https://answers.ros.org/users/5118/roman27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-19**:
hm... That's odd. Why don't you try using the gui_command program? Just rosmake it and see if you can control it. It's in the vanderbilt-ros-pkg.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
do a rostopic list and post the output for me

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
Hm... Ok. Now do an rxgraph and post the screenshot. (sudo apt-get install rox-groovy-rxgraph)

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
After you install it, just run the command "rxgraph" with no rosrun in front of it.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
By the way, feel free to just email me if you have p2os specific questions: hunter.allen@vanderbilt.edu

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
This is entirely my fault. You were publishing to the wrong topic... You need to publish to "/cmd_vel." Check the code I put in my answer.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
Also, do a git pull in the root of the vanderbilt-ros-pkg. I forgot to change that code back, so I have been doing that on the wrong topic as well. It should work now. So sorry for that.

**Comment by [roman27](https://answers.ros.org/users/5118/roman27/) on 2013-06-20**:
Thanks no problem in the meantime i figured it even out by myself ;) (the /cmd_vel problem)  and finally got to drive it :) the rxgraph is a really good thing thanks for that. Now i hope we can finally start with our project :). Thank you very much for the help.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-20**:
Glad to hear it! I'm glad I was able to help. Learning to debug with ROS is an important thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No... Sorry for the misunderstanding... You need to create a package. Navigate to your ROS workspace (for you it should be done by `cd ~/ros_workspace`) then run the following command.

```
roscreate-pkg p2osTutorial roscpp geometry_msgs nav_msgs
```

Then add the following line to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(eo_pose src/eo_pose.cc)
```

Note: you need to move your source to the subdirectory `src`.

---

Update: I have now added a new tutorial called [Setup.](http://ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials/Setup) I also updated the tutorial you are using with some more detail.

---

Ok, so I see the confusion now... You will not need to run any g++ commands at all. If you have not done so, I recommend that you go through the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) to get a better understanding of how the build process works. To answer your question, yes, it is a package. You will have ROS run the program with a `rosrun` command.

---

I think I know the issue... You might not be enabling the motors. Run the `p2os_dashboard` and enable the motors. Alternatively, you can use the vanderbilt-ros-pkg. A lab member wrote a node to do this. It's called p2os_enableMotor.

Here's how you can use it:

```
roscd && cd ../src
git clone https://github.com/allenh1/vanderbilt-ros-pkg.git
source ../devel/setup.bash
rosmake p2os_enableMotor
rosrun p2os_enableMotor enableMotor
```

That should make the pioneer movable. The motors are not enabled by default.

---

Huzzah! I see it now. The controller node is not interfacing with the p2os node. Could you email me/post the code for your controller? I want to make sure there isn't something weird going on.

---

My goodness... This is my fault. Try this code:

```
const double TWIST_LINEAR = 0.5; //.5 m/s forward
const double TWIST_ANGULAR = 0; //0 rad/s 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    
    ros::Publisher cmd_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 100);
    
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_msg;
        cmd_msg.linear.x = TWIST_LINEAR;
        cmd_msg.angular.z = TWIST_ANGULAR;
        
        
        cmd_pub.publish(cmd_msg);
        
        ros::spinOnce();
        
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-19**:
I updated the setup tutorial to give you some more information.

**Comment by [roman27](https://answers.ros.org/users/5118/roman27/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thanks we test it tomorrow it is already late here ;) regards